# PHP-JWT user in token

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, lumen

In my php api(framework lumen), I'm retrieving user data along with token.
I want to put this user data into a hashed token.

My current code look like this:

```
    if (! $token = $this->jwt->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
        return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
    }

    $user = $this->jwt->user();

    return response()->json(compact('token', 'user'));
```

Comment: What are these methods?
jwt->attempt($request->only

Comment: $token->data->user->id...

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this for hashing data

```
                   $key= "User access token";                  // create a key

                    $hash_data= array(
                    "email" => $email,
                    "password" => $password,
                );

               $access_token = JWT::encode($hash_data, $key);
               return response()->json(compact('token', 'access_token '));
```

In **$access_token** details will be in ***encrypt*** format, when you want only decode it

Comment: Yeah, but I want to have it all in one variable - token. In nodejs I can do sth like this: const token = jwt.sign({ user: user }, process.env.SECRET_TOKEN);

Comment: in $access_token , you may find one token(encrypted email and password ). both are in one variable. when you decode it you will get both email and password in array

Comment: The point is that I don't want to create $access_token,  instead I want put user data into existing $token